Is it feasible to create a 40-page booklet in Adobe Illustrator?
I know Adobe Illustrator, but I don't know InDesign. I've also noticed, that Illustrator becomes slower with more artboards, so I'm in a predicament.
Should I work on the software I know and hope for the best? Maybe create that document in multiple parts i.e. 4 documents 10 pages each etc? Or should I just learn InDesign, because there's no way I can do 40 pages in Illustrator?

It is impossible to know because we do not know the file size or the content or the capabilities of your computer. I would say that you should try.
Just save in incremental files. BookletPart1-01.ai, BookletPart1-02.ai

Thank you for your input. I apologize for not being detailed enough. It will be full of both vector and raster imagery, my pc is an average one, with a gtx 970 and 16gb ram

If your in a hurry you need to use software you are familiar with of course. But in the long run you should definitely learn InDesign. It's much better suited for multipage documents in so many ways. You won't look back.

IMHO it would be less than ideal because Illustrator has no master pages, and text handling and styling is pretty rudimentary by comparison.  It will make the job more difficult than it needs to be.  By analogy, it would be bit like trying to use a surgical scalpel to cut bread into slices, when what you really need is a bread knife.

@BillyKerr, or the other way around ...

@Wolff Well, yeah, the wrong tool for the job essentially. Or like using a hammer to fix a screw - I mean you could, but would you really want to. LOL

It is impossible to know because we do not know the file size or the content or the capabilities of your computer.
I would say that you should try. Prepare 1 page and duplicate the content over the 40 pages to see how the file/computer reacts.
I'm not sure if Illustrator has master pages to edit common elements across artboards. Keep that in mind.
One thing I do is save in incremental files. BookletPart1-01.ai, BookletPart1-02.ai to have some backups.
In any case, merge several PDF files is very easy.

I would say that if the booklet is mostly text-based, you will have trouble making it consistent in Illustrator. If the booklet is not intended for professional print, you could even consider using a Word processor but depends on the type of design and the complexity or modularity of the elements.

One option is that you try Indesign for one afternoon with specific objectives. Masterpages, importing AI and PSD elements, Title and Text styles...
Of course, depends on the time you have for the project.
